# Extending vector iterator to fill my needs

Tags: c++, templates, iterator

I have the following design in one of my projects:

```
template<typename C> class B {
    int numValue;
    C inner;
}

template<typename C> class A {
    vector<B<C>> container;
    ...
    Iterator InsertItem(C item) {...}
}
```

What I want is a way to modify the existing vector iterator to return an Iterator which will return **&inner** on dereferencing instead of returning a reference to a B object.
Hope it doesn't need a complete iterator class implementation.

Comment: Why not just do `iter->inner`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your iterator returns `&inner`, how will you ever access `numValue`?

If you create your own A::iterator, it should be easy to have it contain a `vector<B<C>>::iterator` and forward most operations through it. Yes you'll need a full iterator class implementation, but it won't be difficult at all.

Comment: I think I'll write my own iterator type with an embedded vector<B<C>>::iterator as you suggest, but I can't find a good tutorial on writing custom iterator; should I make it inherits from std::iterator ?

Comment: @user456668: Yes, you should inherit from `std::iterator`, though this just provides some typedefs and makes `iterator_traits` available for the type. Otherwise you'll just have to overload all operators that `vector::iterator` does (forward to the underlying iterator) and do the special things in operators `*`, `->` and `[]`.

Answer (score 2):

Such an iterator is [Boost.TransformIterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html)

Example (filling in your code, not that it is particularly good design).

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <boost/iterator/transform_iterator.hpp>
using namespace std;

template<typename C> struct B {
    int numValue;
    C inner;
};

template <class T>
struct get_inner: std::unary_function<B<T>&, T&>
{
    T& operator()(B<T>& value) const { return value.inner; }
};

template<typename C> struct A {
    vector<B<C> > container;
    typedef boost::transform_iterator<get_inner<C>, typename vector<B<C> >::iterator> Iterator;
    Iterator InsertItem(C item) {
        B<C> b = {0, item};
        container.push_back(b);
        return Iterator(--container.end());
    }
};

int main()
{
    A<double> a;
    A<double>::Iterator it = a.InsertItem(3.14);
    std::cout << *it << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Indeed, this seems the less painful solution, but I don't like the idea of introducing some boost depedencies in my project.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where you need to modify an iterator at all. Rather, you just need to add a few member functions to B that return appropriate iterators to inner:

```
template <class C>
class B { 
    C inner;
public:

    typedef typename C::iterator iterator;
    typedef typename C::const_iterator const_iterator;
    // etc.

    iterator begin() { return inner.begin(); }
    iterator end()   { return inner.end(); }

    // and so on for rbegin, rend, cbegin, cend, ...
};
```

Edit: I should add that if you want to support (for one example) `back_insert_iterator`, you'll also need to add a `push_back` to B, which you'll also (probably) implement by having it forward to `C::push_back`.

Comment: Where does the question say or imply that `C` is a container class?

Comment: @Mark: An iterator implies iteration. Since B isn't a container class, for iteration to make much sense, C just about needs to be. If C isn't at least vaguely container-like, what will the iterator iterate over? Granted, C could be an array (for example), in which case you'd need to do more of the work yourself, but absent a specific statement to the contrary, I'd assume he's sensible enough to avoid using raw arrays.

Comment: `A` contains a vector, I assumed that was what needed to be iterated.

Comment: If that's what he's after, he's basically got things "inside out" -- what he needs has little to do with iterators at all, but a way to make B act as a proxy for C (which is fairly simple, but *completely* different).

Answer (score 0):

Use [`boost::transform_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html) to create a new iterator that wraps your vector iterator, but yields the `inner` value instead:

```
template<typename C>
C& getInner(B<C>& b)
{
    return b.inner;
}    

vector<B<C>> container;
typedef boost::transform_iterator<C&(*)(B<C>&), vector<B<C> >::iterator> inner_iterator;
inner_iterator it=boost::make_transform_iterator(container.begin(), getInner<C>)
```